GCS Fuse is not working in CronJob in Google Cloud
I am trying to access and write CronJob logs to google storage buckets. I have already setup the service account and another deployments are using the same using annotations
gke-gcsfuse/volume: "true"
This annotation is not working in CronJob apiversion: batch/v1
The PV and PVC are described in pod spec as per rules.
How can I mount a bucket to CronJob using gke-gcsfuse?
Like other deployments, the CronJob should also mount the bucket as mounted volume.

In GKE you can use CSI ephemeral storage volume in a Job workload where using CSI ephemeral volumes, you are still responsible for creating the buckets before use and deleting the buckets if needed.

The example you referred is good. But How can I schedule a job. Does "Kind: CronJob" not support this annotation?

There is no document suggesting Cronjob,  can you create a new Issue Tracker thread describing your issue. If you have paid support try create an issue.

@SaiChandraGadde, Can you give me an example, where I can expect a job which is never ending. Means , it will continue to remove pods once task is done and will keep creating  new pods?

I solved it after studying the core logic behind CronJobs and Jobs , regarding their schema design. We need to append a Job template in CronJob Template in CronJob .spec.jobTemplate.
